# Maven: how to address config files in directory packaged inside a JAR

Tags: java, maven, jar

My Java project is subdivided in single task artifacts (written by collagues) and in a "collector" artifact developed by myself, all run with Maven.

Usually in my pom.xml file is composed by several dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.foo.project1</groupId>
            <artifactId>project1</artifactId> 
            <version>4.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.foo.project2</groupId>
            <artifactId>project2</artifactId> 
            <version>1.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.foo.project3</groupId>
            <artifactId>project3</artifactId> 
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

So, say that project2 for example has not only .class files packages in the src/ dir and .xml and other stuff in the resources/ dir, but for example resources/ is containing some other text files for various purposes (e.g. presets).

I want to address one of those physical files in the code of my "collector" artifact.
This because in a certain point of my code, I want to call a method of a class comping from "project2" classpath and thus physically from the "project2" JAR;

But while the class hierarchy is ok with the call, the accessory file is not. If in my Java code I address the filename I want to use as "resources/name.txt", the JVM believes to search for the file in my "collector" artifact resources/ dir, which is wrong -- I really want it to point to [project2.jar]/resources/name.txt.

How to correctly address the file packaged inside the project2 jar?

Thanks a million!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to *read* a text files that you have put in the resources directory, you simply have to remember that maven put file in resource directory unchanged in the jar. So you can ask the classLoader to give it to you as a resource :

```
InputStream is = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/data/name.txt");
```

will look for a file named `name.txt` that you initially put in `src/resources/data`

Comment: It works, thanks! Actually it's more useful to me to use .getResource() in URL format, but you nailed the solution.